# Problem when sending mail with Zend Mail?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I'm trying to send an e-mail with ZendMail ( this simple script sums it up )

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('My Nice Test Text');
$mail->setBodyHtml('My Nice Test Text');
$mail->setFrom('test@example.com', 'Mr Example');
$mail->addTo('contact@mypage.com', 'Mr Test');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send();
?>
```

However I get this stack trace:

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137

Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Mail.php(1178): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /var/www/hexreaction/mail/index2.php(11): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 {main} thrown in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php on line 137
```

EDIT:

I'm not trying to use SMTP to send my e-mail and I'm having a less horrible problem, but still a problem.

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
$config = array('auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'contact@mypage.com',
                'password' => 'secretpass');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('contact@mypage.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('contact@mypage.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send($transport);
?>
```

This throw's this error, I don't really get why:

```
Fatal error:
Class 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp' not found in /var/www/hexreaction/mail/index3.php on line 7
```

EDIT 2:

This is my final working code

```
require_once('Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php');
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
$config = array('auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'somemail@mysite.com',
                'password' => 'somepass',
                'ssl' => 'tls');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('somemail@mysite.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('somemail@mysite.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send($transport);
```

Comment: Updated Goles answer need to add **'ssl' => 'tls',** at top to avoid error
see my answer

Comment: this is incredible; thanks for the update; I'm gonna do that for my questions in the future as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you can see in the Stack trace `Zend_Mail` uses `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail` as transport adapter.
So make sure a sendmail-compatible [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_Transfer_Agent) (e.g. Postfix) is running on your system.

As an alternative you could use the [Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.sending.html) transport adapter and use an external SMTP-Server like so

```
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.example.com', array(
    'auth'     => 'login',
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'port'     => $port,
));
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);
```

Edit:
For your 2nd Problem: a

`require_once('Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php');`

should help.

Comment: I'm trying to use SMTP too, ( edited my post ) , and I'm getting a less horrible error, but still an error.

Comment: Thanks!, also GMAIL expects SSL, so I added my final working code :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another great thing on Zend_Mail is that's chainable, so you can do this:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('My Nice Test Text')
     ->setBodyHtml('My Nice Test Text')
     ->setFrom('test@example.com', 'Mr Example')
     ->addTo('contact@mypage.com', 'Mr Test')
     ->setSubject('TestSubject')
     ->send();
```

Don't know for sure if 'chainable' is the right word, but I hope you got the point. This is just a free tip. The answer is given (right) by Benjamin

Comment: See MethodChaining / Fluent Interface for further information
http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html

Answer (score 1):

Updated Goles answer need to add **'ssl' => 'tls',** at top to avoid errors

```
require_once('Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php');
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
$config = array(
                'ssl' => 'tls',
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'somemail@mysite.com',
                'password' => 'somepass'
                );

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('somemail@mysite.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('somemail@mysite.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send($transport);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to seand mail in magento with attachment have a look on the following snippet

```
$config = array(
                'ssl' => 'tls',
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'hassanalishahzad@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'yourPassword'
                );

        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);


        $bodytext = "Please see attachment for customers detail.";
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setFrom('noreply@yourdomain.com','Hassan');
        $mail->addTo('xyz@yourdomain.com' );
        $mail->setSubject('Customers info');
        $mail->setBodyText($bodytext);

        $file = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($path.$fileName));
        $file ->type        = 'text/csv';
        $file ->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
        $file ->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $file ->filename    = $fileName;

        if(!$mail->send($transport)) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
        echo "File Completed";exit;
    }
```