# How to include Zend Mail library

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, gmail

I want to send email using Zend Mail library. How I have to include it inorder to be able to use it? It says me to configure ini file however I'm using shared hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Problem when sending mail with Zend Mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455674/problem-when-sending-mail-with-zend-mail)

[Zend Mail Gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094137/zend-mail-gmail-smtp)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via your PHP script using: [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

```
ini_set('include_path',ini_get('include_path').':../libraries/Zend');
```

Where `../libraries/Zend` is the path to your Zend Framework library.

Comment: What does ":" mean? Should it be under Zend folder? Will it be able to load Mail folder?

Comment: The ':' is a separator between what is already on the include path `ini_get('include_path')` and what you are adding to it, which in this case is the path to your Zend Framework installation. Also, it will load everything under Zend, so you only want to put it to the top level of your library.

Comment: I have tried ':../Zend', ':/Zend', ':Zend', 'Zend'. Neither one worked. It says: Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp' not found in /users/username/public_html/example.com/email.php on line 8

Comment: The Mail folder is under Zend folder. And email.php is next to Zend folder.